# Porblem in linking input and search

Tags: apex, visualforce, webservices

I want to display materielNumber, materielDesignation , storageLocation , storageLocationDesignation ,quantity on visual force page when I click search button

Here is my sample code:

**My visual force page :**

```
<apex:page controller="Shell_Ws" action="{!neosearch}">

    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Search Records" mode="detail">

            <apex:pageBlockSection >

                <apex:inputText value="{!inputNeo}" label="Enter materielNumber"/>

                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!neosearch}" reRender="resultBlock"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

         <apex:pageBlock title="Results" Id="resultBlock">

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{}" var="">

              <apex:column headerValue="" value="{}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockTable> 

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**My apex class :**

```
public class shell_Ws{



    public List<webserviceclassname.nStockOutput> neolist {

    get{

            if(neolist== null){

                neolist= new List<webserviceclassname.nStockOutput>();           

            }

            return neolist;

        }

        set;    

    }



    public String inputNeo{get;set;}



    public shell_Ws() {



    }





    public void neosearch(){



        webserviceclassname.nStockInput input = new webserviceclassname.nStockInput();

        input.plant='NIME';

input.materielNumber = 'TEST_SHELL';

webserviceclassname.stockSap_ws_provider_Shell_Port port = new webserviceclassname.stockSap_ws_provider_Shell_Port();

List<webserviceclassname.nStockOutput> xxx = port.nStock(input);





for(webserviceclassname.nStockOutput x : xxx ){



    System.debug(x.materielNumber);

    System.debug(x.materielDesignation);

    System.debug(x.storageLocation);   

    System.debug(x.storageLocationDesignation);   

    System.debug(x.quantity);

  }

}

}
```

when i input test_shell in the textfield and i click on search, i should get material number etc, i am not able to link inputNeo and neoSearch so that it display the data.

Help please

Comment: Have you checked if you have a value in the variable inputNeo by adding a system debug or the problem is when the code is not returning when you do a search ?

Comment: could you please give me a sample code on how you would do that, thanks

Comment: System.debug(inputNeo); then check the debug logs, just like you did in the for loop

Comment: Indeed am not getting any return data, any guess why?

Comment: You need to share more code, especially the webservice class. As you are doing an external search you might have connectivity issue, connection times out. Wrap the method nStock(); into a try and catch block.

Comment: Hello @Mihai, 
I've been able to get the data. In the debug log when i run my class, i get my list (webserviceclassname.nStockOutput) as output
but i d'ont know how to output in on my visualforce page here : 

`<apex:pageBlock title="Results" Id="resultBlock">

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{}" var="">

<apex:column headerValue="" value="{}"/>

</apex:pageBlockTable>`

Can you please help me?

Comment: Have a look at apex repeat http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_repeat.htm